# SSRS - nested IIF in the expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, iif-function

`=iif((Fields!Company_OEM.Value = "Channel") AND (Parameters!paramCompanyOEM.Count < 2), "None",  iif(Not(Fields!Company_OEM="Channel"), Count(Fields!TS_ISSUEID.Value), "None"))`

**Error shows and unable to run the report**

Suppose the conditions (first iif) statement lies to the true part which is "None". The false part lies to the second iif statement.

Any guide? Thanks

Comment: The above expression shows error and unable to run the report. 
Suppose the conditions (first iif) statement lies to the true part which is "None". The false part lies to the second iif statement

Comment: A few tips for getting better responses: (1) edit your question and [format it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) so the code looks like, well, code; (2) ask a real, practical question instead of just "need help"; (3) tell us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) yourself to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing a ".Value" at the second test for "Channel". (Happens to me all the time)

```
=iif((Fields!Company_OEM.Value = "Channel") AND (Parameters!paramCompanyOEM.Count < 2), "None", iif(Not(Fields!Company_OEM.Value="Channel"), Count(Fields!TS_ISSUEID.Value), "None"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Count(Fields!TS_ISSUEID.Value).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
=IIF((Fields!Company_OEM.Value = "Channel") AND (Parameters!paramCompanyOEM.Count < 2), "None", IIF(Not(Fields!Company_OEM="Channel"), Count(Fields!TS_ISSUEID.Value).ToString(), "None"))
```

Let me know if your problem resolved or not